# Integrator circuit input signal

Tags: integrated-circuit, integrator

I made an ideal opamp, but I have a doubt regarding using it as integrator. If I give input as square wave, will it affect the bias? As far as I understand usually bias is required after which AC signal would be given for opamp operation. Does it mean square wave should have vbias as DC level?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about a classic op amp based integrator configured with a resistor input and capacitor with large parallel resistor as feedback. If you want to use a single voltage supply (+Vcc and Gnd) then you need to bias the non-inverting input to Vcc/2 and have the square wave input swing symmetrically either side of Vcc/2.

Comment: Thanks for the help @James